# Too much vertical space in a CDF file

Tags: graphics, export, cdf-format

When I prepare a CDF file to be included into a web page, far too much blank vertical space is left over the pane.  Is there a command to reduce that?  This is illustrated by the files [SimpleDemos.nb](http://www.abstractmath.org/Mathematica/SimpleDemos.nb) and [SimpleDemos1.cdf](http://www.abstractmath.org/Mathematica/SimpleDemos1.cdf).

Comment: How did you prepare the .cdf file?

Comment: I made the following guide for myself when CDF first came out.  I understand it is irrelevant now because of Mma 8.0.4, but I would still like to know if there a command that reduces the size of a hidden cell to zero.

Comment: The guide is at http://www.abstractmath.org/Mathematica/MakingPlugIn.pdf

Answer (score 6):

You can easily remove all white space around your CDF app. Simplest way - use **CDF Web Deployment Wizard** available in Mathematica version 8.0.4. It is designed to remove the white space around interactive content and embed it tigtly into a webpage. Follow **File » Deploy » Embed in HTML…** Here is the result of this workflow applied to the app from your file `SimpleDemos.nb` and embeding it [into WordPress](http://kaurov.com/wordpress/?page_id=802).

The CDF file can be downloaded from [here](http://kaurov.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SimpleDemos.cdf)

As you can see there is no horizontal or vertical white space around the app.

I would also recommend controlling the size of embedded CDF with `ImageSize->{w, h}` option for your internal graphics in `Manipulate[...]`. Actual app size on the page will be slightly larger due to `Manipulate[...]` interface with dimensions provided by the wizard. If you would like detailed instructions follow this [video](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/02/22/mathematica-qa-series-cdf-embedding-in-a-nutshell/).

Comment: I will be able to download 8.0.4 in a couple of months, so that will solve my problem.  Thanks.